# Symfony 5.3 The parameter "21" must be defined

Tags: php, symfony

i developed a symfony project.
Everything words fine on dev machines (using symfony server on port 8000).

When i clone the git in my production server i got this error:

> Executing script cache:clear [KO]  [KO] Script cache:clear returned
> with error code 1 !! !!   // Clearing the cache for the prod
> environment with debug !!   // false !! !! !!  In
> App_KernelProdContainer.php line 674: !! !!    The parameter "21" must
> be defined. !! !! !!  cache:clear [--no-warmup]
> [--no-optional-warmers] !! !! Script @auto-scripts was called via
> post-update-cmd

I tried to:
delete the var/cache/* content
execute a php bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.global_clearer
set the env to prod and to dev

Nothing changes.

I have an ubuntu 20 with php-fpm7.4, mysql 8.0.

The error log shows:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException:
> The parameter "21" must be defined. in
> /var/www/html/lavanderiasolari/public_html/laundry_manager/var/cache/prod/ContainerJ6TfZkC/App_KernelProdContainer.php:674\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> /var/www/html/lavanderiasolari/public_html/laundry_manager/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/EnvVarProcessor.php(281): ContainerJ6TfZkC\App_KernelProdContainer->getParameter()\n#1
> [internal function]:
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\EnvVarProcessor->Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\{closure}()\n#2
> /var/www/html/lavanderiasolari/public_html/laundry_manager/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/EnvVarProcessor.php(277): preg_replace_callback()\n#3
> /var/www/html/lavanderiasolari/public_html/laundry_manager/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php(415):
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\EnvVarProcessor->getEnv()\n#4
> /var/www/html/lavanderiasolari/public_html/laundry_manager/var/cache/prod/Contai...'

I executed composer dump-env .env and he generated .env.local.php, with

return array (
'APP_ENV' => 'prod',
'APP_SECRET' => 'c6e083dd648f30951fb991cee1df42f9',
'DATABASE_URL' => 'mysql://[DBUSER]:'.urlencode('[dbpasswd]').'@127.0.0.1:3306/[dbname]?serverVersion=8.0',
);

What shall i do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems like you're having an env variable setted localy but not on the machine you've deployed

Comment: I executed composer dump-env .env and he generated .env.local.php, with array
return array (
  'APP_ENV' => 'prod',
  'APP_SECRET' => 'c6e083dd648f30951fb991cee1df42f9',
  'DATABASE_URL' => 'mysql://######:'.urlencode('######').'@127.0.0.1:3306/######?serverVersion=8.0',
);

Comment: Can you search your config for `21` or possibly `%21%`? It doesn't have to be an envvar, it can also be a regular parameter. Maybe it's a url where you need to escape `%`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4):

Having the same error. The problem is comming from special characters in your password.
Indeed in .env variables you need to url encode. For example != become %21%2F but it cause error

> The parameter “21” must be defined

Solution in config/packages/doctrine.yaml replace

```
url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

by

```
url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
```